# Which domain trusts to reset during forest recovery? Incoming, outgoing or both?

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller, trust-relationship

- I understand the difference between an outgoing and an incoming trust
- I understand that the trust flow goes into one direction and the direction of access is the other way around
- I understand that being the domain with an incoming trust, we are the ones who can access the other domain
- I understand that being the domain with an outgoing trust, we are the ones who get accessed

Now I am doing a forest recovery and have to reset one side of the trust for security purposes as outlined in this Microsoft document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/forest-recovery-guide/ad-forest-recovery-reset-trust

The root domain in the forest obviously has both incoming and outgoing (two-way) trust relationship to its child domains. Now the following part of the Microsoft documentation I do not understand.

> Reset the password on only the trusting domain side of the trust, also
> known as the incoming trust (the side where this domain belongs).
> Then, use the same password on the trusted domain side of the trust,
> also known as the outgoing trust. Reset the password of the outgoing
> trust when you restore the first DC in each of the other (trusted)
> domains.

I fail to understand which trust I have to reset, being in the root domain. The incoming ones? The outgoing ones? Do I have to do anything on the other side, in the remote domain?